# Turn off camelcase JSON serialization for certain classes

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, ado.net

Hope that someone can help me with this seemingly simple problem.
In short, I want to use camel case for all property names, except when the property is a DataTable. In that case, I want the column names to be unchanged when serialized.

I have a rather deep object structure that I serialize to JSON, using JSON.NET. I want the property names to be camel case, and I dont want to put attributes on every class, so I use the following code:

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    private static DefaultContractResolver _contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
    };

    public static string SerializeObjectToJson(object obj)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = _contractResolver
        });

        return json;
    }
}
...
string json = JsonHelper.SerializeObjectToJson(myDataDTO);
```

That works fine. However, I also have ADO.NET DataTable properties, and in that case I want to keep the case of the column names unchanged.

Simplified example here:

```
public class MySampleDTO
{
    public Object Data { get; init; }
    public int SomeInteger { get; init; }
}
...
// Get table with columns "Period", "Sales" and "Expenses"
DataTable myDataTable = ...
MySampleDTO dto = new MySampleDTO() {
   Data = myDataTable,
   SomeInteger = 3
}
string json = JsonHelper.SerializeObjectToJson(dto);
```

The resulting JSON becomes:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "period": "2004",
      "sales": 400,
      "expenses": 700
    },
    {
      "period": "2005",
      "sales": 500,
      "expenses": 900
    },
    {
      "period": "2006",
      "sales": 720,
      "expenses": 420
    }
  ],
  "someInteger": 3
}
```

Obviously, the column names of the data table are serialized as camelcase which is not what I want (but I want "SomeInteger" to be camel case)

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Json.NET` uses a [`DataTableConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_DataTableConverter.htm) to convert a `DataTable` to and from `JSON`.

This one shares the same serializer with all other converters that are being used for the (de)serialization of an object, in this case one configured with a camel case naming strategy.

In order to apply a different naming strategy for a `DataTable`, you can implement a custom `DataTableConverter` in which you configure the `serializer`  to use a different `IContractResolver`/`DefaultContractResolver` without the camel case naming strategy while (de)serializing the `DataTable`.

Alternativelly you might set up a whole different serializer that you pass to `base.WriteJson` and `base.ReadJson`.

---

```
public class CustomDataTableConverter : DataTableConverter
{
    private static readonly IContractResolver _contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var contractResolver = serializer.ContractResolver;

        try
        {
            serializer.ContractResolver = _contractResolver;
            base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
        }
        finally
        {
            serializer.ContractResolver = contractResolver;
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var contractResolver = serializer.ContractResolver;
        object value = null;

        try
        {
            serializer.ContractResolver = _contractResolver;
            value = base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
        }
        finally
        {
            serializer.ContractResolver = contractResolver;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

---

You add this `CustomDataTableConverter` to the converters of your `JsonSerializerSettings`.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
    },
    Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented        
};
settings.Converters.Add(new CustomDataTableConverter());

var datatable = new DataTable();
datatable.Columns.Add("Period", typeof(string));
datatable.Columns.Add("Sales", typeof(int));
datatable.Columns.Add("Expenses", typeof(int));
datatable.Rows.Add("2004",400, 700);
datatable.Rows.Add("2005", 500, 900);
datatable.Rows.Add("2006", 720, 420);

var dto = new MySampleDto
{
    Data = datatable,
    SomeInteger = 3
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto, settings);
```

The columns of the `DataTable` in the `JSON` result will now be `Period`, `Sales` and `Expenses` as expected.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "Period": "2004",
      "Sales": 400,
      "Expenses": 700
    },
    {
      "Period": "2005",
      "Sales": 500,
      "Expenses": 900
    },
    {
      "Period": "2006",
      "Sales": 720,
      "Expenses": 420
    }
  ],
  "someInteger": 3
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot!
I don't understand how JSON.NET "knows" that is should use the CustomDataTableConverter when (de)serializing DataSets. 
Is that because CustomDataTableConverter is a sublass of DataTableConverter?

Comment: @FredrikGunne `Json.NET` will look for a converter that can handle a `DataTable`, which `CustomDataTableConverter` does since it inherits from `DataTableConverter` and which gets priority over the regular `DataTableConverter` since explictly configured in the settings.